# Ways to test Nuxt.js frontend and Laravel Backend

Tags: laravel, jestjs, laravel-dusk, nuxt.js

I am looking for ways to test both Laravel API and Nuxt.js (frontend) at the same time.

A simple case where I want to test is the contact form. I can use jest to test that I submited the form and confirmation message appeared and I can test the api that when receiving certain data it returns ok but what would be the correct way for an integration test of the two?

For example if I want to test that by submitting the form the data are stored in the database?

I think the way to go is Laravel Dusk. Is this right? Can it be used for testing Nuxt.js? If so, how would I do that?

I have two different repositories, and in my laravel travic ci i git clone the nuxt.js and build it.

Can I just target the nuxt url with dusk? Or are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Yes, you can use Dusk to test your site. Dusk simulates user actions, so you can basically test any site with it. Have you looked at the documentation? Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: On what exactly?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir say the nuxt app is launched on 127.0.0.1:3000. How would I setup Dusk to target that page?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?